# Usar Core Data ou outra API para interagir com o sqlite?

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

Estava pesquisando sobre meio de salvar dados no iPhone e iPads e me deparei com muitas opções, cada uma com a sua complexidade e finalidade. A Apple recomenda que qualquer que seja o app, que se use o Core Data, que nada mais é que uma camada para interagir com um banco SQLite. Também vi que há opções de trabalhar diretamente com SQLite sem o uso do Core Data, se utilizando de funções  com base em linguagem C, onde você atua diretamente no sqlite.

Eu gostaria de saber, sobre a experiência de vocês, quando se deve usar APIs de terceiros, frameworks de terceiros, ou o próprio Core Data.

Comment: Eu uso o sqlite3, e uma classe para realizar as funções.

Comment: Sim eu usei o sqlite3 em um projeto recentemente, mas achei um tanto "trabalhoso". Outro dia vi um comentário, onde o cara dizia que: usar funções C para tratar um BD, é quase o mesmo que ser sadomasoquista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu particularmente prefiro o Core Data, no começo pode parecer um pouco estranho, mas não é tão complexo de se usar.

Caso você tenha uma versão do seu app para Android eu recomendo que você use o SQLite direto, pois assim você consegue usar o mesmo banco para as duas plataformas.

Fica a dica de leitura

- [Básico de Core Data para iOS](http://grupomobilidade.wordpress.com/2012/08/07/basico-de-core-data-para-ios/)
- [iPhoneDevBrazil › Core Data X SQLite](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/iphonedevbrazil/IPtT1Pw5w4k/n7wqDbiHI1cJ)

Comment: Obrigado!! Eu tinha começado a estudar o Core Data. Obrigado pelos links também.